# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 - 0,0% displayed in graphs

Tags: oracle, graph, business-intelligence, oracle12c, obiee

I am facing problems with graphs in the latest OBIEE release (12.1.2.2).

In OBIEE Version 11.1.1.7.1  the 0,0%, as shown in the picture, is not displayed.

However, in OBI 12.1.2.2 the bar graphs display for some reason 0,0%. Rebuilding the graph will not change the display. Editing the options is no help.
See [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc1jJ.png)

Is there any other way to change this behaviour?

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Is that the 11 screenshot or the 12 one? "as shown in the picture" sounds like it's 11 but then the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi Christian, the screenshot is from 12. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I quickly built one in OAC (kinda 12.2.1.3) and the 0,0 is always rendered, yes. It's a valid number rather than NULL so I guess it does make some sense. If this disturbs you I'd say open an SR and see what they say. Don't hold your breath though.

Comment: However, some other bar graphs (migrated ones as well as newly built ones) are not displaying the 0,0. So apparently in general, it does not display the 0,0 - only due to specific constellations maybe?

Comment: Is there actually a 0,0 present in the data set? I forced it using divisions so that there was always some data present (i.e. 0,0). 

Other than that if you have to many slices in your stack it will anyways not render everything (gui overload) and drop some value displays.